# CFDocument: coldfusion.document.spi.DocumentExportException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfdocument

I am trying to create a pdf using `cfdocument` but ColdFusion keeps throwing an exception and I can't find a way to work around this.

This is the code that I am using:

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" filename="rep_report.pdf" overwrite="yes" name="rep_report">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <style>
          <cfinclude template="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
      </style>

      <cfinclude template="views/_reputationTable.cfm">  
  </body>
</html>
</cfdocument>
```

And this is the exception:

```
An exception occurred when performing document processing.
The cause of this exception was that: coldfusion.document.spi.DocumentExportException: java.lang.NullPointerException.

The error occurred in E:/sites/xAmplifier.com/admin/rep_report_template.cfm: line 43
Called from E:/sites/xAmplifier.com/admin/wheels/events/onrequest.cfm: line 1
Called from E:/sites/xAmplifier.com/admin/rep_report_template.cfm: line 43
Called from E:/sites/xAmplifier.com/admin/wheels/events/onrequest.cfm: line 1
41 :       </style>
42 :       
43 :       <cfinclude template="views/_reputationTable.cfm">  
44 :   </body>
45 : </html>
```

It seems that my issue is the part where I am trying to include a template but unfortunately I don't have a way around this.

Any suggestions on how I can keep the included template and use cfdocument?

Comment: Why are you including the style in the body? Why not just use the normal method? `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" />` in the header?

Comment: Originally this was an email template and as you may know the normal method will not work. I can change that but my issue is coming from the second include file not the first

Comment: What CF version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is a CF8 and CF9 bug. I am unsure that this bug was fixed with CF9.1

http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2008/1/11/CFDocument--pdf-generation-broke-after-CF8-upgrade

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Based on the article I am going to have to add the query name in front of every variable inside the cfdocument which is going to be annoying and tedious... Will keep you posted.

Comment: I tried following the solution of the author in the article you posted but my issue still remains.

Answer (score 1):

I find sometimes when CFDOCUMENT breaks that the easiest path to finding the underlying problem is to use CFSAVECONTENT to generate the HTML, then pass the completed and expanded HTML to CFDOCUMENT to render it. That way, if you do hit an error in HTML generation, the error itself will be obvious.

This also minimises the time the document rendering is taking place, which is single-threaded unless you are using CF Enterprise.

Comment: I found a new version of my HTML broke the pdf, discovered I had not promoted an image for the new HTML. Promoting the image fixed the HTML, and pdf works again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a font is specified for each text element.

Comment: Can you add more context as to why this might fix the problem?

Comment: The error "coldfusion.document.spi.DocumentExportException: java.lang.NullPointerException" is pretty generic. It vaguely specifies something went wrong while converting the HTML into PDF.
I had a similar issue where I was not able to render even a "Hello World" into pdf.
Then I replaced <cfoutput> Hello World </cfoutput>
with  <cfoutput>  <div style="font-family: monospace"> Hello World </div> </cfoutput> 
and then it started rendering properly.
In the code in this question also, I suspect there might be an issue with how the styles are imported.