# cfdocument tag suddenly throwing "This function should be called while holding treeLock." error

Tags: coldfusion

I have an application that contains a form which, until recently, I was able to save as a PDF using cfdocument. A few weeks ago we swapped out a server. The old server was running CF 9.0.1. The new server is CF 10. Since then, I've been getting this error when I try to save this particular form as a PDF.

--

> An exception occurred when performing document processing. The cause
>   of this exception was that:
>   coldfusion.document.spi.DocumentExportException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This function should be called while
>   holding treeLock.

--

I have another page in the application that saves PDFs just fine. It's just this page that's throwing the error. I can't find anything about TreeLock anywhere on the web (at least, nothing that pertains to ColdFusion).

Has anyone else run into this, and if so, how did you fix it? Thanks!

Comment: could you please share your code?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945698/cfdocument-coldfusion-document-spi-documentexportexception-java-lang-nullpoint

Answer (score 0):

I started getting the error upon promoting a new version. Rendered the content in HTML. Found I had forgotten to promote an image (got the dreaded X for image). Promoted the image, cfdocument pdf works again. (I'm using `localUrl="yes"`)

In other words, you can debug CF errors that halt the process but cfdocument pdf blithely assumes HTML content you supply is correct and complete.

Comment: I also discovered by trial and code whittling: `cfdocument format="pdf"` freaks out over  `<input type="button">` and poorly formed `<table>` - missing </tr> for example; while `<input>` and `<input type="checkbox">` are OK

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and by process of elimination found that cfdocument doesn't like textarea elements within the form. It is fine with input type=text, but whenever I tried to add textarea elements it fell over with this error. Hope this helps someone